# Flutter: How to copy and paste same style on widgets? (to apply same properties repeatedly on children)

Tags: flutter, nested, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

**1. Background**

I want to apply same style on several widgets. First, I tried 'wrapping'. I wrapped all widgets or children that needs same style to one container or raw/column, but this didn't allow me to control specific styles on specific child.

**2. Example**

Suppose that I want to make three icons on the app bar with same padding. Here is my example code.

*1) using row wrap*

```
actions: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,200,0),
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.search),
              Icon(Icons.menu),
              Icon(Icons.notifications)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
```

I expected three icons may separate with right-padding(200), but the entire row was moved with right-padding(200), without having changes on padding of each icons.

*2) applying the style one by one*

```
         actions: [
        Row(
          children: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 200, 0),
              child: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 200, 0),
              child: Icon(Icons.menu),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 200, 0),
              child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
```

got the result what i want, not the solution that i need

**3. Question**

I really want to know how to apply same style (or just same padding) to the children, not by controlling every components one by one.

Imagine if the icons were 300, not 3. I may had to control each padding one by one. It might be a padding hell..

[The result of the first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXS3U.jpg)
[The result of the second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpjyg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about making classes. That's what you need, you just want to do your code shorter. You need to make class called for example button, in there you must to add parameters and invoke this class button whenever you want to use it.
Here's good video about it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgQJJ0y0A6w

Comment: ask if you want, I suggest you to understand but if you can't i will try to help you implement the code

Comment: First of all, thanks for kind and appropriate answer. Your explanation helped me a lot. Honestly, I've never took care of the Material Apps & Scaffolds' components. After I watched video through your link, I noticed that the widgets I've been using frequently are all the components of basic classes, and this principle can apply to any other classes. This means, I could make my own 'class' and define repeated styles and variables at once (The best function that i needed to solve the problem!!)

Comment: Again, Thanks a lot for helping me!! If there is any misunderstanding, please tell me!! I always welcome any explanation.

Comment: Nice, i am happy i could help.